# jQuery Mobile slider handle moves past track at one end

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

So the issue I am having is that my slider handle appears to move past the limit of the track when i move it to it's minimum value (farthest left). You can see what I am talking about below as the first slider's handle still lies within the track, but the handle of the second slider seems to overshoot it by a few pixels.

How would I offset the handle here? Or is there something I can change with the track to fix this problem?

Thanks!

[image: Slider offtrack]

Comment: Don't you have any code we could base our answers on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have changed the size of the track and the handle via CSS. When you change the handle size, you need to change the negative left margin to half the width of the handle. Also, reducing the border radius of the track a little will help with the visuals:

```
.ui-slider-track, .ui-slider-switch {
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
.ui-slider-track .ui-btn.ui-slider-handle {
    width: 16px;
    height: 36px;
    margin-top: -20px  !important;
    margin-left: -8px !important;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/TL7M2/9/)**

Answer (score -1):

You could tweak this in CSS. Open up dev tools and play around with padding-left margin left on the slider handle element.

Not ideal but I've had to do similar in the past.